# Syntax error unexpected token error in Open cart 1.5.6

Tags: opencart

have done manual installation of opencart in hostfree server but when i start doing a demo checkout ,while clicking on viewcart it show "SyntaxError: Unexpected token< ok {"country_id":"222","name"............ on message box. i think it has to be loaded in the substate box below country. the same proble i have seen in the admin section while editing store location.

Please help i am new in opencart. also installed vqmod .

https://lh5.googleusercontent.com/-D2PCJ_C_WGw/UhisF6SZCNI/AAAAAAAAAZA/-hjPpFJkrOM/s711/openkart.PNG

Answer (score 0):

You have an error thats being displayed on the page that's being called via ajax. Check your error log for the error in admin section.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply Thevproblew was arised from hosting server.